# Unable to close ssh-connection while running a remote Jupyter Notebook in tmux

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, jupyter-notebook, tmux

I use Jupyter Notebook on a remote machine, where I log in via `ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 <user@IP>`. (Both my machine and the remote machine use Ubuntu). I start a detachable session via `tmux` (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session)) on the remote machine, and execute `jupyter notebook`. Them I am able to run my remote notebooks in my local browser, at `localhost:8000`. The runtime of my notebook is several hours, so I want to be able to close the ssh-connection in the meantime. So I detach the current `tmux`-session (with ctrl-b d). Now, in my understanding, I should be able to simply close the ssh-connection to the remote machine by `exit`. If I leave my browser window open, I expect the (remote) Jupyter Notebook to be still running in the browser.

However: I am not able to close the ssh-connection. Typing `exit` does not close it (but just lets me wait), and if I force a quit via ctrl-c, the notebook in the browser looses the connection to the remote machine.

Am I making a mistake here? Or do I actually need the ssh-connection established so that the notebook in the browser stays connected?

Comment: Just to be clear. You start jupyter notebook with or without `--no-browser`?

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity! Without `--no-browser`. I've edited the post to be more specific.

Comment: I still do not understand it. You are writing you make a connection to a remote maching, but the ssh connection in which you map the ports points to a localhost `ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 <user@IP>`?

Comment: Like this I can run the notebook on the remote machine, and display it on my local machine's browser (in port 8000). But maybe that's the key: if I close the ssh-connection, the map to the port disappears as well?

Comment: Can you please try `ssh -N -f -L 8000:localhost:8888 <user@IP>`? This will put the forwarding to the background. I think this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I use following commands.

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8888 <user@IP> "jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888"
```

If you press Ctrl+C, it kills ssh only. I am not sure if it is error or not.

You can kill notebook by:

```
ssh <user@IP> "jupyter notebook stop 8888"
```

Or you can use: **nohup**